# A line in Hall's proof that the Lie algebra is the tangent space to the Lie group at the identity

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am having trouble understanding the highlighted line below from Hall's book: Lie groups, Lie algebras and representations.

[image]

I suspect that this line follows from this theorem: 
[image]

Here is my attempt to verify this line:

By Theorem 3.42, we know that in a small enough neighbourhood $0 \in U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, there exists a function $\delta: U \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ such that $\gamma(t)=e^{\delta (t)}$ for all $t \in U$. We know $\gamma$ is smooth. Does that mean $\delta$ must also be smooth?

Comment: $\gamma'(t)= e^{\delta(t)} \delta'(t)$

Comment: This is the chain rule. But doesn't this already assume $\delta'(t)$ exists? It therefore seems circular to use the chain rule to prove $\delta'(t)$ exists

Comment: The exponential map is smooth, so log is smooth on $V_\epsilon$.

Comment: @doremifasolatido I was hinting at a contradiction to the smoothness of $\gamma$ if $\delta$ were not also smooth, using what the derivative would have to be if it existed. But Max's idea of applying the log Math makes this much simpler.

Comment: @Max Thanks! I guess the inverse function theorem is key for this argument.